# How can I associate firestore user info with the firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I using Firebase as a backend for my application and have my users stored in a firestore collection. How can I have it so that my users can upload /download data to storage and have it associated with their account. It seems the firestore and firebase storage are two separate entities?

Comment: Cloud Firestore has no concept of "users". Are these Firebase Authentication users? Can you show what you currently have with a screenshot, or code?

Comment: Well, yes I mean authentication users but I have a firestore collection to store more information about them.

Comment: In the same way you use the auth uid for the id a document in Firestore for a user's data, you would use the uid in the path of the storage bucket for a user's files.  But yeah, they are completely different systems.